# Graphviz: Vertical alignment of subgraphs

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to get a graph looking similar to this with Graphviz:

[image]

But using this code:

```
from graphviz import Digraph
G = Digraph()

G.node_attr = {
    "shape": "rectangle",
    "width": "2",
    "height": "2"
}

G.node("A")
G.node("B")
x = "0.5"
G.node("B1", width=x, height=x)
G.node("B2", width=x, height=x)
G.node("B3", width=x, height=x)
G.node("C")

G.edge("A", "B")
G.edge("B", "C")
G.edge("A", "B1")
G.edge("B1", "B2")
G.edge("B1", "B3")
```

I end up with this:

[image]

I want B1, B2 and B3 to be in the same "vertical level" as B. I am sure this can be achieved with subgraphs, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I completely misread your question. I don't think there is an easy solution for this with graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a mostly sufficient workaround by introducing an additional invisible edge and adjusting the node separation.

By simply adding the two lines

```
G.edge("B2", "C", style="invis")
G.attr(nodesep="1")
```

at the end of the code in the original post, one gets the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to **rank=LR** (now ranks are columns)
then put A B and C in the same rank
B1 and B2 in the same rank